# Using Text Filter WebPart, Users cannot Edit in Datasheet

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2007

I added a text filter webpart to my custom list. When I enter in text then select "Edit in Datasheet" option from Actions Menu. I get error

> "Web Part Error: There is no valid configuration for these connected parts to run in."!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Datasheet views don't support Web Part Connections and instead of ignoring them, unfortunately they just fail to display.

In order to make this work you should create and view and then use DataSheet view for editing.